# Applying Material3 colors to OutlinedTextField in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, material-components-android, android-jetpack-compose-material3

**EDIT: Adding more detail - to make code complete:**

I am having challenges applying theme colors to `OutlinedTextFields`, after converting to the new M3 themes.

From what I can tell, there is no direct support for using the new design token colors (`primaryContainer`, `tertiary`, etc) when using the `OutlinedTextField`.

**Question**: Is there a simple way to apply these colors universally?
**Question**: When I apply custom colors, they aren't all applied, and I am not sure why?

What I tried:

This is the function I use to create custom `TextFieldColors`, and how I apply them:

```
@Composable
fun customTextColors(): TextFieldColors =
    TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
        textColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground,
        disabledTextColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground,
        backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background,
        cursorColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground,
        errorCursorColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.error,
        focusedBorderColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
        unfocusedBorderColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground,
        disabledBorderColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground,
        errorBorderColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.error,
        leadingIconColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground,
        disabledLeadingIconColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground,
        errorLeadingIconColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.error,
        trailingIconColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground,
        disabledTrailingIconColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground,
        errorTrailingIconColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.error,
        focusedLabelColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
        unfocusedLabelColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground,
        disabledLabelColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground,
        errorLabelColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.error,
        placeholderColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground,
        disabledPlaceholderColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
    )
```

then applying them in this way:

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardOptions
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.ExpandMore
import androidx.compose.material.icons.outlined.Visibility
import androidx.compose.material.icons.outlined.VisibilityOff
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.IconButton
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource
import androidx.compose.ui.text.AnnotatedString
import androidx.compose.ui.text.SpanStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.*
import com.myApp.demo.R
import com.myApp.demo.data.StaticData
import com.myApp.demo.ui.theme.card_corner_radius
import com.myApp.demo.ui.theme.grey_400
import com.myApp.demo.ui.theme.horizfull_verthalf

@Composable
fun NameTextInput(name: String, onNameInfoValid: (Boolean) -> Unit) {
    // Name
    val nameState = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(name)) }
    val nameString = stringResource(R.string.name)
    val nameLabelState = remember { mutableStateOf(nameString) }
    val isNameValid = if (nameState.value.text.length >= 5) {
        nameLabelState.value = nameString
        onNameInfoValid(true)
        true
    } else {
        nameLabelState.value = stringResource(R.string.name_error)
        onNameInfoValid(false)
        false
    }
    OutlinedTextField(
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(card_corner_radius),
        value = nameState.value,
        singleLine = true,
        onValueChange = { if (it.text.length <= 30) nameState.value = it },
        isError = !isNameValid,
        label = { Text(nameLabelState.value) },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
            keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
            capitalization = KeyboardCapitalization.Words
        ),
        colors = customTextColors(),  // <-- Here is where colors are set!
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(horizfull_verthalf)
    )
}
```

They aren't **all** being applied.

I see the `focusedBorderColor` set correctly, but I don't see `focusedLabelColor` being applied correctly (in this case RED is the correct *primary* color to be applied, so I would want to see the Label also be RED)

[image: outlined text field with focused border set]

Also error is *border* is working, but not for the other attributes:

[image: error text view]

Here is my Theme setup:

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.isSystemInDarkTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.lightColorScheme
import androidx.compose.material3.darkColorScheme
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable

private val DarkColorPalette = darkColorScheme(
    primary = grey_700,
    onPrimary = white_desat,
    tertiary = grey_600,
    secondary = amer_blue,  // TODO desat
    onSecondary = grey_500,
    surface = black_pure,
    onSurface = white_desat,
    surfaceVariant = grey_800,
    onSurfaceVariant = white_desat,
    error = orange_700,
    onError = orange_700
)

private val LightColorPalette = lightColorScheme(
    primary = amer_red,
    onPrimary = white_pure,
    tertiary = amer_blue_50,
    secondary = amer_blue,
    onSecondary = grey_500,
    surface = white_pure,
    onSurface = black_pure,
    surfaceVariant = white_pure,
    onSurfaceVariant = black_pure,
    error = orange_500,
    onError = orange_500,
    errorContainer = orange_500,
    onErrorContainer = orange_500

    /* Other default colors to override
    background = Color.White,
    onBackground = Color.Black,
    */
)

@Composable
fun ComposeTemplateTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colors = if (darkTheme) {
        DarkColorPalette
    } else {
        LightColorPalette
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = colors,
        typography = DemoTypography,
        content = content
    )
}
```

Finally to make this example complete, here is how I call the Composable in the first place:

```
NameTextInput(name = personalInfo.name, onNameInfoValid = { isNameValidState.value = it })
```

...and the versions I am using

```
        appCompatVersion = '1.3.1'
        activityComposeVersion = '1.4.0'        
        composeVersion = '1.0.4'
        composeNavigationVersion = '2.4.0-alpha06'        
        kotlinVersion = '1.5.31'
        ktlint_version = "0.42.1"
        ktxVersion = '1.7.0'
        lifecycleVersion = '2.3.0'
        materialVersion = '1.5.0-alpha05'
```

Comment: Your code changes label color correctly to me. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Works perfectly fine. Please check your imports. If you are partially migrating, there might be some with material3 and some older imports. Especially check files like Theme, Typography, Shapes, etc. I missed those in the first run.

Comment: Also, note material 3 does not have TextField, so TextField is still from Material 2. [Compose Material 3 1.0.0-alpha01 release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material3#1.0.0-alpha01)

Comment: I am aware that TextField is still from M2, and I think this is actually _still_ in that universe (other then the Color names I am using are now from the M3 color theme).

@philipdukhov - are you saying that you DO see the Label be colored correctly, like in my image, the error text would be orange or "Name" would be red?

Comment: @Booger I didn't check the error, but the Name was definitely red.

Comment: @Booger, The code which was working perfectly fine yesterday is not working now. I can reproduce the same issue you have now. I will dig deeper to understand more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems crazy. But this is what happens.

There seems to be some style conflict between Material 2 and Material 3 . (apparently obvious I guess).

Using

```
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
```

[image: Material 3]

But when using

```
import androidx.compose.material.Text
```

[image: Material 2]

This one line change solved the issue.

My complete material imports if needed.

```
import androidx.compose.material.ExperimentalMaterialApi
import androidx.compose.material.OutlinedTextField
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.material.TextFieldDefaults
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.rounded.Clear
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.IconButton
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
```

Additional helpful info,

I am maintaining complete 2 sets of resources.
This might help for components that are not supported in M3 yet.
Use appropriate imports in the composable.
We can use complete imports if a particular composable has both M2 and M3 components.

```
private val Material2DarkColorPalette = darkColors(
    primary = Primary,
    ...
)

private val Material2LightColorPalette = lightColors(
    primary = Primary,
    ...
)

private val LightColorPalette = lightColorScheme(
    primary = Primary,
    ...
)

private val DarkColorPalette = darkColorScheme(
    primary = Primary,
    ...
)

@Composable
fun Material2AppTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    val colors = if (darkTheme) {
        Material2DarkColorPalette
    } else {
        Material2LightColorPalette
    }

    androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme(
        colors = colors,
        typography = Material2Typography,
        shapes = Shapes,
        content = content
    )
}

@Composable
fun Material3AppTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    val colors = if (darkTheme) {
        DarkColorPalette
    } else {
        LightColorPalette
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = colors,
        typography = Typography,
        content = content
    )
}

@Composable
fun MyAppTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    Material2AppTheme(
        darkTheme = darkTheme,
        content = content,
    )
}
```

Comment: This did fix it for me, and explains why other saw this working...I was able to see the correct label color when changing the import.

Thank you. Well worth the bounty!

Comment: I am not seeing the other elements changing (like trailing icon color, etc) - that is a bummer.

For sure the imports between M2 and M3 are going to be a challenge for a while (as long as we need to support both).

Comment: Glad, it works. :)

Comment: Yup, you can try maintaining 2 sets of themes and other resources. That seems to work pretty well for me.

Comment: But the color values I am sending are not from my theme, they being resolved and being sent in as `TextFieldColors` - I think the M3 Text (which I didn't know existed) is not feature complete (and is probably why those colors didn't work).  

But switching to M2 Text does get me closer, so this was a success for sure.  Thanks again.

Comment: Added more info on how I am handling both M2 and M3. Give it a try if it seems helpful.

Comment: Thanks - that is useful.